# scanf keeps \n character in the buffer

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C and i am trying to read 6 `integers` with `scanf` .However, i noticed and read that `scanf` leaves the `\n` char (which i have in my format string) in the buffer thus "reading" an extra input from the user.On various stack posts i read that this can be simply solved by adding a white space in front of the %d format (e.g: `scanf(" %d\n",&var);`but that doesn't work for me.What should i do and why does this happen?

Here's my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int A[2][3] = {};
    int B[3][2] = {};
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < 2;i++) {
        for(j=0; j < 3;j++) {
            scanf(" %d\n", &A[i][j]);
            getchar();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try just `scanf(" %d",&var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\n` in your format string is actually causing a problem.  After reading an integer,  the `\n` in the format string matches any number of whitespace characters, so the function won't return until some  non-whitespace character is inputted.

Change the format string as follows:

```
scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
```

the `%d` format specifier implicitly discards any leading whitespace characters, so no need for a leading space (that's only needed for `%c`).

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Btw, do you mind explaining what you mean by this:`the \n in the format string matches any number of whitespace characters`. I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of it

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail For example, if you type in "123" and hit Enter, you're send ing `123\n` to `scanf`.  The "123" matches `%d`, and the `\n` matches `\n`.  The call to `scanf` won't return however because it didn't get input that failed to match its format.  If you then enter "456", `4`, doesn't match `\n`, so "456" is left in the input buffer and `scanf` returns.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` ignores whitespaces before the number. You only have this problem when you read a number with `%d` (which leaves the newline in the buffer) and want to read a char with `%c` afterwards. There you have to put a whitespace before the `%c`, so that it will ignore the newline in the buffer.

When you want to read numbers only you can use `scanf("%d", &var);`.